# Dealing with duplicate names in Teradata "create table with data"

Tags: sql, teradata

Is there a way to automate dealing with/ignoring duplicate names when creating a new table in Teradata.

Assume I'm joining a table with itself. The table has columns

```
id, email, address1, address2, city, state, zip.
```

,

```
create table mytable2 as (
  select a.*, b.* from mytable a
  left join mytable b on a.email = b.email
  where a.id <> b.id
) with data
```

requires me to write out

```
a.address1 as aaddress1, b.address1 as baddress1, a.address2 as aaddress2...
```

Is there an easier way of dealing with this? When I'm joining many tables, this hurts my productivity. Often these tables are for research and the potential ambiguity is not a problem.

Comment: No way. When you create a table you must assign unique names.

Comment: This sounds like this table is part of a bigger problem you are trying to solve. Purely on face value from the SQL you have provided you have a self-join on a table looking for records that share the same email address. Is the `id` column a surrogate for the `email` as the natural primary key?